# How to render a list in json with Node Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I need render a list with many items, i have this code actually

```
let names = [];
            let id = [];
            rows.forEach(function(row) {
               console.log(row.id + ": " + row.name);
               id.push(row.id);
               temp.push(row.name);
            });
            return res.json({
                "id": id,
                "name":names
            });
```

but i get this as result

```
{"id":[178,179],"names":["andrew","Erick"]}
```

when i need make a list like this

id: 178, Andrew

id: 179, Erick

what im missing?

Comment: How about `return res.json(rows);`?

Comment: yes, thanks this solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
rows.map(row => "id: " + row.id.toString() + ", " + row.name).join('\n')
```

If `rows` looks like this:

```
[
    {id: 178, name: "Andrew"},
    {id: 179, name: "Erick"}
]
```

This will output:

```
id: 178, Andrew
id: 179, Erick
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
rows = [
  {
    id: 178,
    name: "Andrew"
  },
  {
    id: 179,
    name: "Erick"
  }
]


result = rows.map(row => "id: " + row.id.toString() + ", " + row.name).join('\n')
console.log(result)
```

Comment: The problem isn't the formatting but the structure itself. OP mistakenly thought he has to rearrange the DB result, which is what caused the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `rows` equal to:

```
[
{id: 178, name: 'Andrew', other: 'fields'},
{id: 179, name: 'Erick', other: 'fields'}
]
```

You need only to transform your array to another array, and in this case you could use the [`.map`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/map) function:

```js
const myOutput = rows.map(function(row){
 return {
  id: row.id,
  name: row.name
 }
})
res.json(myOutput)
```